# Ruby assignment vs expression modifier precedence

Tags: ruby

I see the following behavior in both MRI 2.0 and jruby 1.7.16.1:

```
irb(main):001:0> a 
NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> a = 2 unless true
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> a
=> nil
irb(main):004:0>
```

I expected `a` to remain undefined because `=` has higher precedence than `unless`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`a = 2 unless true` is evaluated like this:

```
unless true
  a = 2
end
```

precedence doesn't come into play because its a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
a  #=>NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
```

The parser can not decide if this is a local variable OR METHOD, as the error says.

```
a = 2 unless true
```

Here the parser is able to recognize this is meant to be a variable, and it is defined (not initialized). It will be initialized if the statement is executed. Uninitialized variables evaluate to nil.